# Java map to flex object conversion

Tags: apache-flex, object

From java i am sending ordered Map.In flex when i convert that into Object i am loosing the order which i maintained in java.Is there any other way to maintain the order in flex object?

Regards,
Siva

Comment: Show some code.  Sounds like an error in your conversion routine.

Answer (score 1):

Java Maps (including SortedMap / TreeMap) are converted into a generic Object instance which has no notion of ordering:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/serialize_data_2.html#312520

You could perhaps write a custom Java class (and the equivalent ActionScript class) which contains the original Map and an Array of the keys in the correct order.

Comment: For sure, if he doesn't need the keys :)